# wpa_supplicant does not roam based on signal strength but on throughput

Tags: wpa-supplicant

When I use wpa_supplicant for WiFi roaming, I hope the roaming rule to switch from a poor signal AP to a good signal AP(roam based on signal level). However, during testing, I found that wpa_supplicant roam based on estimated throughput. What could be the reason? The following is the output log information.

```
wpa_supplicant: wlan0: 2: 62:90:73:b0:f3:48 freq=2462 level=-70 snr=19 est_throughput=90000
wpa_supplicant: wlan0: 3: 22:90:3d:93:70:af freq=2462 level=-32 snr=57 est_throughput=65000
wpa_supplicant: wlan0: Selecting BSS from priority group 2   
wpa_supplicant: wlan0:    selected based on RSN IE  
wpa_supplicant: wlan0:    selected BSS 62:90:73:b0:f3:48 ssid='1906'  
wpa_supplicant: wlan0: Considering within-ESS reassociation  
wpa_supplicant: wlan0: Current BSS: 22:90:3d:93:70:af freq=2462 level=-32 snr=57 est_throughput=65000  
wpa_supplicant: wlan0: Selected BSS: 62:90:73:b0:f3:48 freq=2462 level=-70 snr=19 est_throughput=90000  
wpa_supplicant: wlan0: Allow reassociation - selected BSS has better estimated throughput
```

I want the roaming rule to switch from a poor signal AP to a good signal AP, no based on throughput.